# jquery datetime picker

Tags: .net, jquery, datetimepicker

Hi
I attach the jquery datetime picker to a textbox using the following (please note that I have specified the format to be dd/mm/yy):

```
$('#SupplierSearch_StartDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

This all works fine on the form. But when I submit me form back to the server, the date that comes back is in the format mm/dd/yy (set on a property in my model. I am using ASP.Net MVC)

Below is my Html help code to generate the textbox:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupplierSearch.StartDate) %>
```

In my model I have applied the following attribute to the property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Can anybody please advise me on how I can get this fixed or point out what I am doing incorrect or missing out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and here is some reference material http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```